# Removing two elements in one line

Tags: jquery, element

Is there a way of completing this script in one line?

```
$(this).next("br").remove();
$(this).remove();
```

I tried `$(this).remove().next("br").remove();` but this doesn't work because we're removing the element before we can find the next one.

Comment: $(this).next('br').remove().end().remove();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) (or its predecessor [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) before jQuery 1.8):

```
$(this).next("br").addBack().remove();
```

Alternately, you can use [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to get back to the previous set of matched elements:

```
$(this).next("br").remove().end()
       .remove();
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Never knew about the `andSelf()` function. You learn something new every day!

Comment: `andSelf()` is deprecated, just FYI. You should use `addBack()`. http://api.jquery.com/addBack/

Comment: Ditto, `addBack()` and `andSelf()` has been hidden from me, after 2 years of using jQuery!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).add( $(this).next("br") ).remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).next("br").addBack().remove();
```